# «З дощу та під ринву» Що означає вираз?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

«З дощу та під ринву» існує такий вираз… але що він означає, я не можу зрозуміти? 
Бо слово Ри́нва (від пол. rynna < нім. Dachrinne — «даховий жолоб») — труба або жолоб для швидкого прийняття і відведення води з даху під час дощу, зливи.

І щось дивний зміст виходить, поясніть будь ласка…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Фразеолоґічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53396/357358.html):

> з дощу́ та під ри́нву. Від однієї небезпеки, біди до ще гіршої. З наймів довелося повернутися до сварливої мачухи, не краще, як з дощу та під ринву (З усн. мови).

Мається на увазі, що і під дощем на людину ллє вода, й під ринвою також не сховатися (навіть ще більше ллє). Тобто, не сховався від проблеми, а одну виміняв на іншу, якщо потрапив з дощу під ринву.

Ось ще [англійський відповідник](https://www.yenotes.com/uk/words/uk/phrase/%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%2520%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%83%2520%D1%82%D0%B0%2520%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%2520%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D1%83/), якщо допоможе зрозуміти:

> It's a game of wack-a-mole

OED:

> Used with reference to a situation in which attempts to solve a problem are piecemeal or superficial, resulting only in temporary or minor improvement.
>   ‘the site's security team has an ongoing battle against spammers, but it's a game of whack-a-mole’

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Тобто під дощем мокнеш, а під ринвою ще більше змокнеш. Була мала проблема, а стало ще гірше.

[Приклад уживання:](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/frazeologizmu/z-doshhu-ta-pid-runvu) *«З наймів довелося повернутися до сварливої мачухи, не краще, як з дощу та під ринву»* (З усн. мови).

Comment: Здається, не містить якоїсь нової інформації порівняно з [відповіддю P. Vovk](/a/3796). Хіба що [посилання](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/frazeologizmu/z-doshhu-ta-pid-runvu), але, по-моєму, його можна було просто додати в коментарях до наявної відповіді. Чи я чогось не помітив? (Може, задля малюнка?)

Comment: @Sasha так, задля малюнку. Можу видалити відповідь, якщо потрібно.

Comment: Мабуть, хай буде.